# Hidden field, safe using?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hidden-field

I am writing a web application on Asp.Net MVC 3.
Assume that we have some page and a @Html.Hidden field there with some information in it. Can I be sure that the user will never reach this information in hidden field?
Shortly speaking: is it safe to use hidden fields for information, that should not be revealed to user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can I be sure that the user will never reach this information in hidden field? Shortly speaking: is it safe to use hidden fields for information, that should not be revealed to user?

Absolutely not. It will still be *sent* to the client - it just won't be visible in the rendered HTML. If anyone uses "view source" they'll still see the field.

I suggest you try it to see for yourself - create the hidden field, then view the page in a browser and select "View Source". It's always good to have some idea of what the generated HTML looks like.

If you *must* send the information to the client, encrypt and sign it first - that way the user won't be able to view it in plain-text, and they won't be able to forge a different value in the response, other than "previously seen valid values".

Answer (score 3):

Any user can right click your form and select View Source. This means that all of your markup (hidden fields incldued) will be visible to the user.

If you don't want the user to see it, don't send it to them. Consider persisting it server side instead.

Comment: +1 for stating the obvious: "If you don't want the user to see it, don't send it to them."

Answer (score 2):

> is it safe to use hidden fields for information, that should not be revealed to user?

Absolutely not. Not only that the user can see the information stored in a hidden field but he can modify it. Never store any sensible information in a hidden field.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake which everyone could make in a asp.net project. The programmer forgot to make the hidden field invisible, so the hidden security info may be viewed on client side.

for example, we have a hidden filed which is like this:

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="job_id" runat="server"  />
```

What is the problem? Well, this hidden value can be viewed by others on client side by viewing the source code in the browser. You will see this.

```
    <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_job_id" type="hidden" value="102" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$job_id"></input>
```

How to correct this? This is the right code. You just need to set the Visible="false".

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="job_id" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

:)

See more details on

[wusit.com/blog/member-blog-details.aspx?upn=uE5GzSGY7UI=&bid=yiDsoLlp+Io=](http://wusit.com/blog/member-blog-details.aspx?upn=uE5GzSGY7UI=&bid=yiDsoLlp%20Io=)

Comment: This is for webforms and the question was about MVC.